# react-query: why is this one query always stale?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I've configured react-query with infinite stale time, per docs, like this:

```
    <ReactQueryConfigProvider config={{
        queries: {
            staleTime: Infinity
        }
    }}>
```

Most of my queries appropriately never go stale, except one, my 'profile' query:

```
const getProfile = async () => {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/user/profile');
        return response.data;
    }
    catch (error) {
        errorCheck(error);
    }
};

export const useProfile = () =>
    useQuery('profile', getProfile);
```

This is the query that holds the current user's profile. `isAuthenticated()` is a synchronous call that checks to see if we have a user token (so I don't make API calls that I know will fail).

For some reason, in the react-query devtools window, this query shows as stale immediately. I really don't see what I'm doing differently with this one. Any suggestions for debugging this?

Comment: Maybe simplifying code a little bit will help. Take a look at `getPokemonList` here:   https://codeworkshop.dev/blog/2020-04-15-fetching-data-with-react-query-and-suspense/

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem,  Jim?

Comment: No, still a problem.  It's not completely blocking me, but it bugs me that I don't know what this is caused by.

Comment: Yes, added my solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think the issue was, and how I solved it.

Because I set `staleTime: Infinity` in my `ReactQueryConfigProider`, I expected all of my queries to never go stale.

What's different about this query is I invalidate it when something not driven by the UI happens.

I have a session timer in my code that, when the session expired, calls `queryCache.invalidateQueries('profile')` to trigger any UI displaying the profile to re-render.

It appears that if `invalidateQueries` is ever called outside the context of a query, the settings in `ReactQueryConfigProider` are not observed, so `staleTime` is set to the default, 0.

To resolve this, for the queries I need to invalidate on a timer, I added `{ staletime: Infinity }` to the query explicitly:

```
export const useProfile = () => {
    const { data: session } = useSession();
    const userId = session?.userId;
    return useQuery(['profile', userId], getProfile, { staleTime: Infinity });
};
```

I won't go so far as to say this is a bug in react-query, but this seems to be a workaround.

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://codesandbox.io/s/honor-prefetch-kkrq1p
Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and it was caused by a component that had a child component which used react-query. Check your component tree and make sure nothing uses useProfile() outside of `<ReactQueryConfigProvider>`.

Comment: I don't understand why having useProfile in multiple places matters.  It woudld just update multiple components, no?